# GoogleCredential won't build without GoogleCredential.Builder

Tags: android, google-drive-api

In the Google documentation for OAuth2, building a `GoogleCredential` with an auth token is described here:

[Credential and Credential Store](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/OAuth2#Credential_and_Credential_Store)

In particular this code snippet is offered:

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
Plus plus = Plus.builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory())
    .setApplicationName("Google-PlusSample/1.0")
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential)
    .build()
```

When I try to build a `GoogleCredential` in this way I am tersely informed:

```
Please use the Builder and call setJsonFactory, setTransport and setClientSecrets
```

in the message field of an exception.  I downloaded the libraries for this last week so I am not sure what is happening.  Is the documentation simply outdated, and if so, what method has replaced this one as best practice for building from an existing auth token and refresh token?

Incidentally, the reason using the Builder was not an option was that there WAS no client secret provided by the Google application console; it says that they are no longer provided for Android apps and the like.  `setClientSecrets(...)`, therefore, couldn't be called.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I am having the same issue.

Comment: We never did.  We ended up putting the documents in a user-controlled google drive, then *sharing* them with a pure machine-controlled google drive, which gave us the same effective control.

Comment: Well it worked for me in someway.. will post is as an answer.. obviously won't be of any help to you now.. but for some other viewers like me.. :)

Comment: Okay, sorry I did not know that android apps do not have client secret.. but do they have an apikey?

Comment: I can't remember (though I think so).  At any rate, though, I always ended up one piece of information short!

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem recently and figured out the solution for my case.

Here is the running conditions: the program is running on Android 4.0 and does not use Google Drive SDK, because it could not allow our program to read the files on Google Drive which are not created by our program. I use the com.google.api.services.drive.* and com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.* Java libraries.

the code arose this problem is like below :

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        httpTransport, jsonFactory, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
    .setAccessType("offline")
    .setApprovalPrompt("auto").build();


GoogleTokenResponse response = null;
try {
    response = flow.newTokenRequest(authorizationCode).setRedirectUri(REDIRECT_URI).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setFromTokenResponse(response);
```

but above code worked well if the parameter to setAccessType("online");

and the resolution for this issue depends on what kind of accessType you want.

if you want "onLine" as the accessType, then use setFromTokenResponse()should be ok.

if you want "offline" as the accessType, then you need to use blow code :

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(httpTransport)
        .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
        .setClientSecrets(CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET)
        .build()
        .setFromTokenResponse(response);
```

One thing need to be mentioned is that you need to keep the accessType setting to be consistent for GoogleTokenResponse and GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow creation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up your Android app key in [Google Dev Console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

1. Choose your project, select API & Auth, then click Credentials
2. Create new client id (though it has other client ids)
3. Select installed app -> android
4. Fill in your package name and SHA1 correctly
5. Create new Key (though it has other client keys)
6. Select Android key
7. Fill in the SHA1;packageName like this: `45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example`

Your problem will be automatically solved. Be sure to create client id and key with both your debug keystore and release keystore.

Answer (score -3):

Check the Android quickstart sample in the Google Drive SDK documentation for step-by-step instructions to correctly setup `GoogleCredential`:

https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android

Comment: That uses `GoogleAccountCredential`, which is for the user's account on the phone.  I want to make an application-managed account using a regular Drive, as described here: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts#use_regular_google_accounts_as_application-owned_accounts I got an auth token and a refresh token and am now having trouble making a `Credential` from them.

Comment: In fact `GoogleCredential` doesn't appear on that page *at all*, just `GoogleAccountCredential`.

Comment: Then, you can check the Java quickstart for that: https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-java

Comment: That needs a client secret, and installed Google API apps (like Android apps) don't have client secrets any more.

Comment: another useless link-only answer